# Minority gate - X will be 1 if a smaller number of inputs is 1 than 0

Tags: circuit, digital-logic

I'm currently constructing the Minority gates problem. Given the value of the output will be 1 if a smaller number of inputs is 1 than 0.

I'm confused with the condition above mentioned  `if a smaller number of inputs is 1 than 0.` Please see the below image with highlighted context. Does it correct? if not then please guide me **what does smaller number of inputs** means ?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R05lR.jpg)

Comment: The provided image does not show output, I think... Is C output? Anyway, if input is [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0] then 1 zero and 5 ones. 1 < 5 so output will be 0. If input is [0, 0, 1, 0, 1] then 3 zeros and 2 ones. 3 > 2 so output will be 1.

Comment: @Jeon - No, C is not an output. The output will be only 1 if a smaller number of inputs is 1 than 0. So my question is does the answer (output) against those highlighted rows will be 1 ?

Comment: I guest that outputs will be 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, from # 0 to 7.

Comment: @Jeon - from which formula you are evaluating this?

Comment: @Jeon - According to my understanding you have constructed this for the following condition - two or more inputs are 0.

Comment: First, from the quote in OP's question. Second, I guess that minority gate is an opposite thing of majority gate https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/boolean_algebra/majority_function.

Comment: No. Counterexample of your guess: If input is [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 3 zeros. But output will be 0.

Comment: @Jeon so what will be your final say on this? will it be 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, from # 0 to 7. ?

Comment: @user6818598, yes

Comment: you are latin?  - Eres latino? - I think so  by the english. I'm too

Answer (score 0):

A, B and C are input.
I define Z as Output

There is not a clear definition of Z = fn(A, B, C)

But... from "`if a smaller number of inputs is 1 than` 0" text, i make this definition...

> ```
> There must be at least one '1'
> The quantity of '1' must be < of quantity of '0'
> ```

So... with this definition I make this table

```
A B C Z
0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1
0 1 0 1
0 1 1 0
1 0 0 1
1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0
1 1 1 0
```

This show that Z = ( A xor B xor C) and not (A and B and C)

That is:

Z1 = one XOR gate with 3 input (A, B, C)

Z2 = one nand gate with 3 input (A, B, C)

Z = Z1 and Z2

This circuit give you the true table I show. Z is 1 only if there is at least one '1' and the numbers of '1' is lower than the number of '0'